# Using Bindy with List

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

i want to use Bindy to map a List of objects.

For Example I have class x:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")    
public class User {
    protected List<Skill> skills;
}        
public class Skill {
    protected String name;
}
```

How can I map skill list from CSV file with the following data:

```
skill1, skill2, skill3
```

I tried @oneToMany annotation but it did not work. Also, don't know how many skill will be included in CSV. How can I handle this mapping?

Comment: Since with BIndy you must specify column position, I strongly doubt it will work with variable length rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using beanio as below

```
 <unmarshal id="convert csv to XML)">
     <beanio id="My list" mapping="MyObject.xml" streamName="ObjectStreamName"/>
    </unmarshal>
```

Also you can define xml file for mapping.